Can't use Cython to compile the Core Library of GeomDL or PyMcubes using --install-option="--use-cython" since "--install-option" is depreciated
I am trying to install Cython compiled versions of GeomDL and PyMcubes packages into Blender 4.1's shipped embedded python (Blender 4.1 is using Python 3.11.7 x64). I'm able to install other packages fine with:
C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.1\4.1\python\bin> .\python.exe -m pip install SciPy etc.
But for GeomDL and PyMcubes, there are additional instructions involving compiling the packages using Cython.
See here, here, and here.
The installation steps state that you should use the following command to install a "cythonized" version of GeomDL:
C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.1\4.1\python\bin> .\python.exe -m pip install geomdl --install-option="--use-cython"
The NURBS-Python docs also give the following examples:
pip install --user . --install-option="--use-cython"
pip install --user . --install-option="--use-source"
python setup.py build_ext --use-cython --inplace

Unfortunately, with the current version of Python that's bundled with Blender 4.1, --install-option has been depreciated and from what I can tell replaced with --config-settings (Here).
So my question is: How can I get compiled, or "Cythonized" versions of GeomDL and PyMcubes to install so I can benefit from the performance increase by installing Cython compiled versions?
Just for broader reference, I am installing these dependencies for the Blender addon "Sverchok". I want to maximize performance as much as I can.
Any help is greatly, greatly appreciated.
